# Right clicking on tkplot has no effect in R studio on Mac?

Tags: r, igraph, tkplot

I'm using `tkplot` to produce an interactive graph. In the `tkplot` documentation it says that the user can right click on an edge and it will display the edge weight. However, right clicking (on a Mac) on the graph only selects the edge and has no other effect?

Below is some simple example code that I was using to test `tkplot`:

```
library(igraph)

edgeW <- c(1,2,10,3,4)  # Edge weight
edgeDir <- c(1,2, 1,3, 1,4, 1,5, 2,3, 2,4, 2,5, 3,4, 3,5, 4,5) #Direction
nodeName <- c("A","B","C","D","E") # Node Names

net.xy <- make_graph(edgeDir, 5, directed = F) # make graph
V(net.xy)$label <- nodeName # set names
E(net.xy)$width <- edgeW # set edge weight

tkplot(net.xy) # plot
```

This opens a window that displays the `tkplot`, but upon right clicking on anything, it just selects the node/edge and doesn't display any information.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: When I run your code in R.app or RStudio, right clicking pops up a menu with entries "Edge color" and "Edge width".  I don't see anything in the docs about edge weight.

Comment: I was using the term edge weight to mean edge width... However, the problem I'm having is when I right click im getting no pop-up menu at all?
Can I ask if you're using a Mac?

Comment: Yes, but not very up to date:  High Sierra 10.13.6.